# Designing a BLE reader to detect nearby bluetooth beacons

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, stm32f0

I am new to this Bluetooth beacons and I'm trying to create a project where multiple BLE beacon readers are installed in a yard which detect the beacon modules and helps to locate the location of each module.

Most solutions online suggest using a mobile phone or pc as the reader but that would increase cost. I have seen projects using raspberry pi but I want to design a reader with something basic as an STM32F0 microcontroller.

So my doubts are if I use beacon such as Gimbal series 10 as my beacon which prefers ibeacon which module should I use for my reader( requirements of the BLE module).

Can i use some modules like HC-05(or maybe something which supports Bluetooth 4.0 or BLE) to continuously scan for nearby Bluetooth devices.

If my choice of beacon is wrong which low cost beacon can be used for this project.

hope i was able to convey my idea.Thank you in advance.

Comment: And how will you detect the location of the devices? Using BT for locating devices in an area has been discussed on this website before. The only information you will get is that a device is in range or it is not. What that range will be depends on the spacing between the beacons and the presence other RF sources like WiFi. BT simply is **unsuited** to do proper location/triangulation. What you can get is in rang/not in range where range depends on many factors.

Comment: I m using multiple readers, so if a bluetooth beacon is detected by 3 readers we can know that it's in a particular area. Also, i read about the RSSI value which gives the level of signal strength. that can also be used for localization. my confusion is about the choice of modules.